# Netbeans 8.0.2 freezing at startup on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

Tags: java, netbeans

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 64bit on my Thinkpad and everything works fine, but I installed netbeans 8.0.2 and when I try to launch it, it freezes at startup during the Loading modules phase.

I have openjdk 8 installed. I don't understand this problem since on 15.04 32bit on another computer it works just fine.

When starting netbeans from command line the message is the following:

chrisgaubla@sokioute:~/netbeans-8.0.2/bin$ sh netbeans

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Me too, also on 64bit. The applications "tvbrowser" and "mediathekview" freeze too - a Java Problem with 15.10?

Comment: Start Netbeans in a terminal and add the messages to your question.

Comment: When starting from terminal here's what I get:

chrisgaubla@sokioute:~/netbeans-8.0.2/bin$ sh netbeans
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Have you tried editing /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties and commenting out the line assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper ?

Comment: After commenting out the line in accessibility.properties as noted above, Netbeans still freezes since I updated to Ubuntu 15.10. It did eventually get past the "Loading modules" - I left the room and gave it about 20 minutes. When I returned it appeared that Netbeans had loaded fine, but my system was totally locked up. Previously, while trying to load Netbeans I noticed that it was pegging one of my cpu's steadily at 100%. I've lost the entire morning fighting this. I'm going back to Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same here. The Java 8 build 1.8.0_66-internal-b01 seems to be a little unstable. You could either wait for a newer build to arrive in Ubuntu (https://tracker.debian.org/news/720431) or use OpenJDK 7 for now.

Edit:
This does indeed seem to be a problem with OpenJDK 8, which still seems to exist is build 66-b17. If you need Java 8, you can download Oracle's JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads and set the path to that JDK in the file <netbeans directory>/etc/netbeans.conf (parameter "netbeans_jdkhome"). I couldn't reproduce the problem with the Oracle JDK.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately the problem still seems to occur with build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17.

Answer (score 18):

To make it work with OpenJDK 8, edit `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` and comment out the following line

```
assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

as suggested here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1510009.

Comment: This was also my problem using java-7-openjdk.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of frustration . Thanks a ton.

Comment: This worked currently for NetBeans IDE Dev and Java: 1.8.0_91. Thanks @binary .